# VB.NET Dashboards for a VB.NET project being that i am a newbie to vb.net

Tags: vb.net, dashboard

can anyone give me sample code on how to create a dashboard using vb.net?
I am new to vb.net development and this is required for the project im handling.
pls help

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to start with WinForms. Here's something from tutorialspoint: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/vb.net_forms.htm